# Can Mods (or I) Undo A Flag?

Tags: support

I had a bit of a screen glitch this morning and accidentally flagged a post as `Rude or Abusive` when it clearly has nothing wrong with it, and I actually wanted to up-vote it. Is it possible for the mods to remove this flag? It resulted in an automatic down-vote and probably has some other minor side-effects I did not desire.

Comment: Seriously? A drive-by down-vote in meta without an explanation?

Comment: I have occasionally thought that I would want to change a flag after I've put it on too, mainly when an OP edits and actually fixes the issue with the post, but also because I've thought 'wrong option' on further consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done this myself in the past. If you click the "flag" link, there's an option to "Retract Flag".

This will show up in your profile's flagging history as "Self Removed":

[image]

I'm not sure whether there's an detrimental things around this however.

Comment: I see it now! Good to know for future miscues (of which there will hopefully be none).

Answer (score 2):

We can't remove it as far as I know (or could find out). But for most flags mods have to act before anything happens, and we can choose not to act :-).

I've removed the flag from the mod to-do flag list.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.